# Можно ли вставить Javascript в Java приложение?

Tags: javascript, java

Можно ли вставить Javascript  в Java приложение?  если да то как?

Существуют ли компоненты в jframe  которые позволяют сделать вставку кода яваскрипта?

Использую Netbeans

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы хотите получить на выходе?  Просто возможность вызывать JS-код (без DOM-а и прочих браузерных фич) из Java кода в качестве скрипта?

Comment: Есть сайт https://ru.tradingview.com/widget/ хочу от туда вывести виджет на java приложение.

Comment: Просто возможность вызывать JS-код  - это все что меня интересует.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA_JavaScript%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вставить WebView со всеми плюшками html+css+js. Можно завеситься на OnLoad.

Вот хороший туториал для JFX: http://habrahabr.ru/company/codeorchestra/blog/198776/

А вот рассказ о том, как этот компонент протащить в swing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374365/integrating-javafx-2-0-webview-into-a-swing-java-se-6-application

Answer (score 2):

> Есть сайт ru.tradingview.com/widget хочу от туда вывести виджет на java приложение.
>
> Просто возможность вызывать JS-код - это все что меня интересует.

Просто *"вызвать код"* и *"встроить в Swing-приложение виджет на HTML/CSS/JS"* - это две большие разницы.

Если речь все-таки о вызове JS-скрипта, реализующего какую-то логику, то в Java 5-7 есть "из коробки" JS-движок *Rhino*, а в Java 8+ новый движок *Nashorn*.

Для затравки пример использования Rhino:

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

engine.put("myparam", "world");
Object eval = engine.eval("function hello(p) { return \"Hello, \" + p; } \n" +
            "hello(myparam)");
System.out.println(eval);
```

Comment: Вы правы, все таки нужно  встроить в Swing-приложение виджет на HTML/CSS/JS"

Comment: Тогда ответ @Globber больше вам подойдет.